# Do you use Scroll View with Constraint Layout?

Tags: android-studio, user-interface, scroll, responsive-design, android-constraintlayout

I was about copying a [Login screen](https://ibb.co/jGSy0L8) from Adobe XD to Android Studio (I just start to learn about this) and I don't understand how you implement the Scroll View in these kind of situations where you can design everything with Constraint Layout except for that little scroll down to read "Already have an account? Sign in"

Pretty much all the tutorials I've watched they use Linear Layout and Relative Layout.

How do you handle this?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use scroll view in constrain layout

```
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark_bc">
        
        
        <!--set here your component like button, textview and other stuff-->
        
        
         </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```